# Router not blocking https

Tags: networking, router, https

We have a Netgear WNR834B wireless N-router. The problem is that its not blocking certain https sites with its content filtering and most said there is nothing much you can do that cant be bypassed with this type of router so i am looking to buy a new one. What router features do i need to look for to be able to block https connections on the router? I don't want to block it in the PC's for most users have admin rights. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As mentioned in your other question, go with a pfsense router. It'll do everything you need and much more.

Comment: As mike pointed out in his answer.  You can't do it man.  HTTPS is meant to be secure for a reason.  Unless you block by IP which is not necessarily a good idea since you don't know what is hosted there.  Could be hosting multiple websites.

Comment: @Matt You absolutely *can* do this. Businesses do it all the time. Ethics aside, it's a trivial exercise to stick squid in place with an SSL bump.

Comment: @Mark, Go with hardware firewall with policy control or proxy packages like squid.

Comment: Sure @EEAA - but this is basically a home router.  I doubt he's running squid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't block https unless you decrypt the traffic somehow. The whole packet is encrypted so the router has no idea what the host header it. It only see's the destination IP and a bunch of encrypted traffic.

Comment: +1 Right.  You can't do it.